# I want to run my codeigniter project on localhost, without defining 'base_url' in config

Tags: php, codeigniter, wamp

I downloaded a codeigniter folder from its official website. Setup it in wamp.
I remove index.php by making setting in .htaccess file.

'I left blank base url in config.'

Now, when i click on link to go to another controller, instead of showing `http://localhost/projectname/cntrlname` url is `http://127.0.0.1/projectname/cntrlname`.

I dont want to set base url. so, what should i do to make it work properly.

Comment: Dont leave base url blank in latest versions of codeigniter `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';` Try some of these htaccess https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Comment: I am using codeigniter version 3.1.3.

Comment: Latest versions 3 and up

Comment: also look into using a .env file so you only have to change the variables once for each level of production

Comment: But its working in 3.0.1

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run your project without define base_url in config.php file. 
You must keep some points in your mind.

1- Define base url as blank in **config.php** file.

```
  $config['base_url'] = '';
```

2- You also leave index_page as blank in **config.php** file.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

3-  You must load **helper url** in **autoload.php** file, which is define in config folder.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

4- Suppose your project folder name test. then i write htaccess for that project for example.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|cache|images|js|css|fonts|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I did exactly as you mention above in htaccess. But, still my link is http://127.0.0.1/project/contrl

Comment: actually localhost map on this ip(127.0.0.1).so this ip is include in your url. you check in window director. `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` in hosts file.

Comment: But why it is showing in URL? It must show the project name.

Comment: ok, but if you comment in hosts file then it will not showing in url. like this `# 127.0.0.1       localhost`           or add this line in hosts file.

Comment: It is already available in my hosts file                                                            # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
# 127.0.0.1       localhost
# ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost